# How to get a wrapped set containing the last of a certain element within other elements?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, wrapper

In jQuery I want to get the last of a certain element within a set of elements. For example I have these DIVs with children:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the last div with class "inside" in each of the divs with class "test". Something like this:

```
var customWrappedSet;
$('.test').each(function()
{
    customWrappedSet.add($(this).find('.inside').last());
});
customWrappedSet.text('hello');
```

This would ideally be three elements (the last .inside in each .test). The result would look like this:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is the last-child selector, rather than simply last. This will return every element that is the last child within it's parent:

```
$('.test .inside:last-child');
```

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/ucaAs/)

Comment: Great fiddle by the way. You helped me get my first jQuery plugin working: [jQuery.coolType](http://jsfiddle.net/Chevex/GSe9U/13/)

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjwkg/)

```
$('div.inside:last', 'div.test');
```

Use can use the ':last' pseudo class to match the last element. The second parameter here scopes the search for elements matching the first selector to only div's with a class of 'test'.

Comment: He wants EVERY .inside that is the last-child of the parent .test. See my response for the distinction.

Comment: And that's exactly what he'll get with my code. As I explained, the second parameter scopes the first selector. Check console results in the fiddle to see it in action.

Comment: Yes, right. I was doing some lazy reading. Out of curiosity, is there ever an advantage to using the kind of scoping you did? I'd argue that my example is both more syntactical and easier to write.

Comment: I just asked a question about performance between the two methods yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086099/which-jquery-selection-method-is-faster