# Which jQuery selection method is faster?

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm wondering if there's any advantage to using the context parameter when making selections with jQuery versus using a normal CSS scoped selector.

Assuming I have this html:

```
<div class="contacts">
    <h1>All contacts</h1>
    <div class="contact new">
        <p class="name">Jim Jones</p>
        <p class="phone">(555) 555-1212</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact new">
        <p class="name">Bob Smith</p>
        <p class="phone">(555) 555-1213</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact new">
        <p class="name">Dave Baker</p>
        <p class="phone">(555) 555-1214</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <p class="name">Pete Harrison</p>
        <p class="phone">(555) 555-1215</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <p class="name">George Donald</p>
        <p class="phone">(555) 555-1216</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <p class="name">Chris Root</p>
        <p class="phone">(555) 555-1217</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I want to grab all new contacts (marked by 'new' class) from the contacts div, which method is faster, scales better, etc..?

```
$('.contacts .new');
```

Or

```
$('.new', '.contacts');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/cvWA7/)

**Update**

There's a lot of great info strewn throughout the answers and comments. To summarize the major points, in most browsers a single selector scales better when there are multiple .contacts divs. The two selector context method is faster, in most browsers, with only a single .contacts div present.

Something useful to take away from that is we can use one method when selecting inside an element with an id.

```
$('p:first', '#chapter2'); // get the first paragraph from chapter 2
```

And use the single selector method for instances where we're selecting from a potentially large group of elements.

```
$('.chapter p:first-child'); // get the first paragraph from all chapters
```

Comment: What did you discover when you tested them?

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to ask and you end up getting more info. For example, here I learned that jsperf exists. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Against all (my) odds, seems number 2 is the fastest.

Check [it here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selection-method)

Comment: +1 (if I hadn't reach my limit today) I'm surprised the difference is so large as well.

Comment: Indeed uh? I thought the single selector was fastest :S

Comment: My 2 cents about why this is so: jQuery can detect that each of the selectors is a simple class lookup and so it delegates both to the highly optimised browser function `getElementsByClassName`. When they're in one string, it can't make such an optimisation and would use `querySelectorAll` or its own methods to find it.

Comment: This limit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits

Comment: I just ran it in Opera. Check out the result. It's the third test I've run that suggests they have a *highly* optimized `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @nickf i guess that would make sense. Sidenote: Firefox 6 is faster than Firefox 5. But there is a huge difference between Firefox 5 and Firefox 6 using the two selectors

Comment: Wow, that is crazy. I seriously just tried my own jsPerf test with the slug 'jquery-selection-method' and was informed that it was already in use.

Comment: Wow, I wonder if we could get a jQuery dev to explain that one.

Comment: @nickf: I'd be inclined to agree with that too.  Easiest way to check would be to test in IE8, which has `querySelector` but not `getElementsByClassName`. Like I said in my answer, method 2 is more likely to become slower when more `.contacts` elements exist.

Comment: @patrick: I've noticed Opera's lightning speed for qsa in the past, too.  In fact, the speed of all their DOM methods never ceases to impress me.

Comment: @Andy E, i'm pretty sure `getElementsByClassName` has been around since IE6 times. Do you mean the opposite (querySelector/gEBCN)?

Comment: @Andy E: I was about to consider using it more, but then I discovered that it crashes whenever I try to open Dragonfly!!! Not good.

Comment: @nickf: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html IE just started supporting `gEBCN` in IE9.

Comment: @nickf: what patrick dw said :-) patrick dw: yeah, Dragonfly is just too slow for my liking.

Comment: Thanks, Pablo! This is exactly the sort of info I was after. And thanks for making me aware of jsPerf in the process.

Comment: As others have noted, when you have multiple .contacts divs, a single selector pulls ahead in performance. http://jsperf.com/jquery-selection-method/6

Answer (score 1):

`$('.contacts .new')` should, in theory, scale better because it makes only a single call to the selector engine.  For `$('.new', '.contacts')`, a minimum of two calls are made to the selector function — first to get all elements with class name `.contacts`, and then further calls for each `.contacts` element returned.

In summary, as soon as more `.contacts` elements are thrown into the HTML, a loop is required for the second method and it will slow down significantly.  If you're not going to have more `.contact` elements, you should be using an ID which would be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/cvWA7/1/

The results I am getting are that the first selector, `$('.contacts .new')` is roughly 22% faster.

**UPDATE** Interesting that Pablo got conflicting results. I wonder if there is something wrong with my test.

**UPDATE 2** This was run on Chrome 13

Comment: The performance varies greatly depending on what browser you test it in. The single selector is about 200% faster in Opera, for example.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, `$('.foo', '.bar')` delegates to `$('.bar').find('.foo')`, so the second should be faster.

The reason `$('.foo', '.bar')` is faster than `$('.foo .bar')` is because its executed as native `getElementsByClassName` by sizzle. A case of a selector that just contains a single class name is checked very early in the code, before any complicated logic is executed.

*update*: like I thought, using find() is slightly faster: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selection-method/2

*update 2*: I looked it up in jQuery's code - `$('.foo', '.bar')` does delegate to `$('.bar').find('.foo')` - https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L171.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is **undocumented**, so you should not use it at all.

The `context` parameter should be:

> A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

A string is neither of those.

So, you should create a jQuery object from the selector before using at as context:

```
$('.new', $('.contacts'));
```

As you are making two jQuery calls, that should be slightly slower. However, both expressions basically do the same work so the difference should not be that big.

#### Edit:

Testing how the methods scale: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selection-method/4

Shows that the performance differs between browsers. The single selector is slower in most browsers when you have a single `.contacts`, except Opera where it's really fast. With multiple `.contacts` elements, the single selector scales better.

Comment: nice i added that test case in Pablo's post and it's a lot more inline for what it should be. So this does show that it is using getElementByClassName now, which would be faster than queryall.

Comment: Your scalability test seems rather moot, considering that if there is only one `.contacts` element, an ID would be the better option (e.g. `$('.new', '#contacts')`) and should be even faster.  If there are multiple `.contacts` elements, the second method may not scale so well.

Comment: @Andy E: You have a point there. I edited the test to have multiple `.contacts` elements, and the single selector handles that better.

Answer (score 1):

Of your two examples the first selector would probably be faster.  However, if you assign the context to a variable then use the second method it is MUCH faster.

```
contacts = $('div.contacts');
$('.new', contacts);
```

You can see results at http://jsperf.com/jquery-context-with-tagname.  If you had a larger HTML document prefixing the class with a tag name would also likely yield better performance.